# Поиск сообщений от конкретного адресата IMAP.search()

Tags: python, email, search, imap

Вопрос по imaplib. Необходимо найти все письма от конкретного адресата. В папке Inbox/TestFolder есть только одно письмо. Поисковая строка

```
typ, data = con.search(None, 'FROM "name.surname@testmail.com"')
```

не находит ничего, в то время как

```
typ, data = con.search(None, 'FROM "Surname, Name"')
```

находит это сообщение.

```
print(message['From']) // вывод: "Surname, Name" <name.surname@testmail.com>
print(type(message['From'])) // вывод: <class 'str'>
```

На сколько я понимаю, `search` должен искать подстроку в строке, но этого не происходит. Я могу найти письмо по любому символу, который есть в строке "Surname, Name", хоть по запятой, но любые попытки найти именно по адресу результата не дают. То есть, поиск успешно проводится по первой части строки, где имя и фамилия, но игнорируется вторая часть строки, в которой сам адрес. Есть идеи, в чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877529/imap-search-for-email-address-in-the-from-field

Оказывается, нужно отдельно указать, что поиск производится в хедере:

```
typ, data = con.search(None, 'HEADER FROM "name.surname@testmail.com"')
```